# Get text between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In Javascript I want to get a string representing all the text between two parentheses, even if that string contains more parentheses.

It would work as follows:

**"(a) (b) (c)".match(SOMETHING);**

> ["a","b","c"]

OR

> "a"

**"((a) (b) (c))".match(SOMETHING);**

> "(a) (b) (c)"

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: /\(([^)]+)\)/ - but it returns ["((a)", "(a"] for the string "((a) (b) (c))"

Comment: I'm pretty sure such a language is not regular, because a recognition engine would require a stack (or otherwise use a non-constant amount of memory). A regular expression is not likely to be the correct tool for the job.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. From my CS class I think it would require a Turing machine, but I don't know how to implement such a thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))
```

---

## How it works

- `\(` matches opening brackets
- `\)` matches closing brackets
- `[^\(\)]` matches anything apart from more brackets
- `*?` add a zero or more times quantifier to the above pattern (made lazy by `?`)

---

## JavaScript implementation

Try:

```
your_string.match(/(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))/g)
```

Comment: "((a) (b) (c))".match(/\([^\(\)]*?\)/) - but it returns ["(a)"]

Comment: Don't bother explaining, doesn't work (Try `((a)b(c))`)

Comment: Doesn't work but thank you for the regex explanation.

Comment: @Carnic Check my edit! :D just need some non capturing groups

Comment: '(a) (b) ((c)) (((d)))'.match(/(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))/g)
["(a)", "(b)", "(c)", "(d)"]

Answer (score 0):

Do you care if the parens match?
If so you will have to use a stack you can't do it with regular expressions.

Try something like this:

```js
var str = "aaa((0)12(2))bbb";
var stack = [];
var result  ="";
var start = false;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  switch (str[i]) {
    case '(':
      stack.push('(');
      if (!start) {
        start = true;
        continue;
      }
      result += str[i];
    break;
    case ')':
      if (stack[stack.length - 1] === '(') {
        stack.pop();
        if (stack.length === 0) {
          start = false;
          continue;
        }
        result += str[i];
      } else {
        //not balanced!
      }
      
    break;
    default:
      if (start){
        result += str[i];
      }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In my scenario, the parens would always match. Thank you, this answer is solid.

Comment: So my question actually asked for the text **inside** the parenthesis. So I tweaked your code a bit.